# DropPHP api in error when start to connect

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

We want to upload file and getting file from dropbox how its possible.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(tokens/bM3yJkFD24AuFqWP.token) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\DropPHP\sample.php on line 106

Could not store token! Make sure that the directory 'tokens' exists and is writable!
```

this error is occurs I am create Dropbox Apps also then this error hows to resolved

Demo download from :: http://fabi.me/php-projects/dropphp-dropbox-api-client/

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but *does* the directory 'tokens' exists, and *is* it writable? :-) Also, you might be better off using the official Dropbox PHP SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php.

Comment: where we create 'tokens' directory??

Comment: and hows change their permission?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved easily by creating the folder "tokens" in the same directory.

You should set this folder writable (set the rights to 777).